# Syslog buffering

Tags: syslog, syslogd

I have a large number of "client" machines (Mac Minis running OS X 10.6.3) that need to send data to a central server, also running OS X, so I am using remote syslogging to accomplish this.

My question is, if the server (or the a client) goes offline for whatever reason, is it possible for the client machines to buffer the log data so that it is not lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For syslog no. There is another syslog implementation called rsyslog ... which supports another protocol named relp. This is exactly what you want for your case.

Comment: +1; we use rsyslog as well for the same reason--it will buffer it locally for a configured amount of time, and will send all data to the server once its re-established the connection.

Comment: The only question now is ... if it's supported by OSX  :>

Comment: Ok, thanks Nikolaidis and Redmumba, rsyslog doesn't actually come with OS X by default so we're going to try a different approach instead of using syslog, as opposed to installing third-party software on all of our clients. But thanks heaps for the answer.